# Solve for the angle UFO with the russian triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

I know that this question has been posted already, but I saw that is possible to draw the triangle of the question inside of the russian triangle. Can someone help me to finish the question using this?
[image: Triangle of the question]
[image: Russian triangle]

I find a lot of angles and I got the equation $∠UFO+∠UFN=100°$, but I couldn't find the value of $∠UFN$

Comment: What do you mean, @Tas ? To solve the first problem by using the second? In any case, show please your attempts.

Comment: @Tas: is $BAC$ isoscel?

Comment: @Tas I got $\measuredangle UFO=75^{\circ}.$ If you want to see my solution, show your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I find a lot of angles and I got the equation $\angle UFO+\angle UFN=100°$, but I couldn't find the value of $\angle UFN$. Please, can you post your solution?

Comment: @Matteo yes! The triangle ABC is isoscel.

Comment: AHA!  I've always suspected UFOs were a Russian plot!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg , please,can you post your solution?

Comment: Please recall what you mean by "russian triangle" in this context (not the film...). For the classical problem (second figure), a reference : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle

Comment: @user247327 I like your comment. Too few humor on MathSE...

Comment: Not an answer, but this might help. If $Q$ is $EFU$'s circumcentre, $\angle FQU=2\angle FEU=10^\circ$. It is sufficient to prove that $QOU$ is straight, whence $\angle QUF=85^\circ\implies\angle EUF=20^\circ$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find angle UFO in the picture attached](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903838/find-angle-ufo-in-the-picture-attached)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $OF\cap UE=\{D\}$ and $\measuredangle UFO=x$.

Thus, $\measuredangle DUF=95^{\circ}$ and since 
$$\frac{OD}{UD}\cdot\frac{UD}{FD}\cdot\frac{FD}{ED}\cdot\frac{ED}{OD}=1,$$ by law of sines we obtain:
$$\frac{\sin65^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}}\cdot\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin(95^{\circ}-x)}\cdot \frac{\sin5^{\circ}}{\sin80^{\circ}}\cdot \frac{\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin35^{\circ}}=1 $$ or
$$\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin5^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}=\sin95^{\circ}\cot{x}-\cos95^{\circ}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin5^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}-\sin5^{\circ}=\cos5^{\circ}\cot{x}$$ or
$$\tan5^{\circ}\left(\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}-1\right)=\cot{x}.$$ 
We need to prove that: 
$$\tan5^{\circ}\left(\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}-1\right)=\tan15^{\circ}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}-1=\frac{3-\tan^25^{\circ}}{1-3\tan^25^{\circ}}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}=\frac{4-4\tan^25^{\circ}}{1-3\tan^25^{\circ}}$$ or 
$$\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}=\frac{8\cos10^{\circ}}{1+\cos10^{\circ}-3+3\cos10^{\circ}}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin65^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}=\frac{2\cos10^{\circ}}{\cos10^{\circ}-\cos60^{\circ}}$$ or 
$$\frac{\cos25^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{\sin20^{\circ}\cos10^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}=\frac{\cos10^{\circ}}{\sin25^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}$$ or
$$\sin50^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}=\sin20^{\circ}(1+\cos20^{\circ})$$ or
$$\sin60^{\circ}\cos40^{\circ}-\cos60^{\circ}\sin40^{\circ}=\sin20^{\circ},$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Oh! Nice answer! But, how do you solve this trigonometric  equation? I wrote $$\frac{2\cos35°-\sqrt2}{16}=\sin95°\cot x-\cos95°$$. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Tas If you can use a calculator, so just calculate $\arctan$. I am ready to show that $75^{\circ}$ is an unique root of the equation without calculator.

Comment: I want to see this without calculator. If you can, thank you!

Comment: @Tas I posted. Your second problem we can solve by the similar way.